# Solution by set Algebra Instead of Venn diagram for following question

Tags: elementary-set-theory

(P ∩ Q ∩ R) U (P′∩ Q ∩ R)U Q′U R′

I am able to solve the set algebraic equation through Venn diagram and the solution is as under:

[image]

set 1 = $(P ∩ Q ∩ R)$ is region 1

set 2 = $(P′∩ Q ∩ R)$ is region 2

set 3 = $Q'$ belongs to regions 4+3+6+8

set 4 = $R'$ belongs to regions 4+7+5+8

and the union of set 1 {1} set 2 {2} set 3 {4,3,6,8} set 4 {4,7,5,8}

will be {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8} that is the universal set itself. I am able to get the correct answer but my approach is through Venn diagram. But some where I have found some algebraic approach through some set operation that I am not able to understand. Can somebody please guide me? 
Following is the link of the algebraic approach.
[Please click here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gate-gate-cs-2008-question-2/)

Comment: You can start applying [Distributivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_sets#The_fundamental_laws_of_set_algebra) to $(P \cap Q \cap R) \cup (P′ \cap Q \cap R)$ to get  $(Q \cap R)$.

Comment: Then apply [De Morgan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_sets#Some_additional_laws_for_complements) to $(Q′ \cup R′)$ to get $(Q \cap R)'$.

Comment: Now you have : $(Q∩R) \cup (Q∩R)'$.

Comment: Got it . Thank you @Mauro ALLEGRANZA